# Why does Wired Network Settings say Link Speed 10 Mb/s

Tags: network-manager, ethernet, settings

I am quite sure my Lenovo Thinkpad L570 has a Gigabit (1000 Mb/s) Ethernet interface. So why does the wired Network Settings say Link Speed 10 Mb/s? (Speedtests often say more than 200 Mb/s upload and download.)
OK. Here comes the output of "$ sudo lshw -C network":

```
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (4) I219-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 21
       serial: 98:29:a6:7d:c9:bf
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.1-4 ip=192.168.0.163 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:129 memory:f2700000-f271ffff
```

I presume "size: 10Mbit/s" corresponds to the line "Link speed 10 Mb/s" in Ubuntu Network Settings.

Comment: You can install `ethtool` and then run `ethtool` on the port in question and it should show you what your link speed is.

Comment: I could show it to you if askubuntu.com had an option for uploading a screen shot.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network`... this will show your link speed... and if you're only getting 10Mb then you've probably got a cable problem. Describe your wiring from the Thinkpad to the modem/router.

Comment: @HenrikR. It's because that kind of data doesn't belong in the comments, but rather, as an edit to your original question. Paste the text, select the text, click the {} icon to format the text. Then you can delete your last three comments. Remember to describe your cabling for me.

Comment: I guess the line "size: 10Mbit/s" corresponds to what is showed as "Link speed 10 Mb/s" in Settings.

Comment: @HenrikR. and lshw shows other info also... like driver, duplex, capacity, etc.

Comment: @HenrikR. still waiting to hear about your cabling...

Comment: NB! Maybe I haven't expressed myself well. It is not a speedtest that says 10 Mb/s. Ethernet-cables: I have a Cat 5E cable from the laptop to my tp-link AC1900 Gigabit router and a 10-15 meters Cat 6 cable to the wall-plug. Does that answer your question? :-) Thank you for you help.

Comment: One thing you could try is a full power reset of the system.  Remove all power from the laptop and if it has a removable battery, remove it too.  Once all power is removed press the power button a few times to drain the board.  If the battery is not removable, power off the laptop then hold in the power button for 15+ seconds then power it back on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sudo lshw -C network` shows us that you've only got a 10Mb link on your ethernet port. Your ethernet card can handle 1Gb, so you're really losing a lot of speed.

98% of the time this indicates a cable problem. You need to be using a `cat 5E` or `cat 6` cable. Try replacing your cable and then recheck `lshw`. 1% of the time it means that the ethernet card is not auto-negotiating the link correclty. Another 1% is due to a router problem with its LAN ports.

**Update #1:**

Power cycling the router and the computer solved the problem.

**Update #2:**

There's still a partial problem. Try connecting/disconnecting the laptop DIRECTLY to the router and/or DSL/cable modem. Retest. Check the settings in the router to make sure the LAN port that your using for the laptop is set to 1G (as opposed to auto). Retest. Use `ethtool` to force your laptop to use 1G instead of auto-negotiate. Retest.

**Update #3:**

```
  ethtool -s devname [speed N] [duplex half|full] [port tp|aui|bnc|mii]
          [mdix auto|on|off] [autoneg on|off] [advertise N] [phyad N]
          [xcvr internal|external] [wol p|u|m|b|a|g|s|f|d...]
          [sopass xx:yy:zz:aa:bb:cc] [msglvl N | msglvl type on|off ...]
```

`sudo ethtool -s enp0s31f6 speed 1000 duplex full autoneg off`

Now shows...

`sudo lshw -C network`

```
*-network 
    description: Ethernet interface 
    logical name: enp0s31f6 
    size: 1Gbit/s  <=== correct value
    capacity: 1Gbit/s 
    width: 32 bits 
    clock: 33MHz 
    configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.1-4 ip=192.168.0.163 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s resources: irq:129 memory:f2700000-f271ffff
```

Comment: OK. I changed the cable from the laptop to the router  to another Cat 5E cable, and ran "sudo lshw -C network". It still says " size: 10Mbit/s". Should I try resetting or power off the router?

Comment: @HenrikR. just to be clear, you have a cat 5E cable that goes to a wall plate, and then a cat 5E cable from the wall plate to the router, yes? Yes, UNPLUG the router from AC, shutdown the computer, plug in router, wait 30 seconds, boot computer. If it still shows 10Mb, do one of two things... connect a cat 5E cable from the computer DIRECTLY to the router and recheck. If that doesn't work, enter the router's admin page and make sure the LAN ports are set to 1Gb.

Comment: Shutting down and powering off both the laptop and the router solved the "Link Speed 10 Mb/s" problem. Now it's back to "Link Speed 1000 Mb/s". And speed tests confirms that things work. PS: There is a Cat 5E from the laptop to the router and a Cat 6 from the router to the wall.

Comment: Thank you for your help! But the problem is only 50% solved, in the sense that if I disconnect the cable to the Ubuntu Lenovo L570 laptop and connect it again, the settings show "Link Speed 10 Mb/s" again, and then I have to shut down everything again...

Comment: @HenrikR. Try the other things that I mentioned earlier. Try connecting/disconnecting the laptop DIRECTLY to the router and/or DSL/cable modem. Retest. Check the settings in the router to make sure the LAN port that your using for the laptop is set to 1G (as opposed to auto). Retest. Use `ethtool` to force your laptop to use 1G instead of auto-negotiate.

Comment: Thank you for the extra info on "ethtool". But it has a huge amount of options. First I need to figure out what is the DEVNAME of my Ethernet port. I guessed 'eth0', but that didn't work. Then I tried "$ sudo lshw -C network" which gave me a 'logical name enp0s31f6', so I will try with that.

Comment: Should I set both 'speed' and 'autoneg'?: <pre>ethtool -s|--change DEVNAME Change generic options
  [ speed %d ]
  [ duplex half|full ]
  [ port tp|aui|bnc|mii|fibre ]
  [ mdix auto|on|off ]
  [ autoneg on|off ]
</pre>

Comment: @HenrikR. before I discuss the ethtool with you, tell me about what happened when you connected the computer DIRECTLY to the router and/or DSL/cable modem. What about the router's LAN port settings?

Comment: As I said from the start, my laptop has always been connected to the TP Link router with a Cat 5E ethernet cable. I don't have a modem. The router is connected to an ethernet outlet on my wall, installed by my ISP, Andels.net. I have logged in on my router (http://192.168.0.1). The connection to the laptop is 1000Mbps full duplex. The other 2 connections are only 100Mbps.

Comment: @HenrikR. sorry for the duplicate questions... when you help so many people... and there's much time between comments... sometimes it's difficult to remember what you've already done :-) See Update #3 in my answer. Report back.

Comment: I ran "sudo ethtool -s enp0s31f6 speed 1000 duplex full autoneg off". And then: <pre>$ sudo lshw -C network
*-network
description: Ethernet interface
logical name: enp0s31f6
size: 1Gbit/s
capacity: 1Gbit/s
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.1-4 ip=192.168.0.163 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
resources: irq:129 memory:f2700000-f271ffff
</pre> NB! It's still "autonegotiation=on". BTW: I run 18.04 LTS, so I will try upgrading to 19.04 now!

Comment: @HenrikR. It's so difficult to read that kind of data when put into comments... they should be edits to your original question. However... after the ethtool command, lshw indicates that it's operating at 1Gb. Isn't that working now?

Comment: Let's drop this discussion. We are talking at cross purposes. :-)

Comment: @HenrikR. How are we discussing at cross purposes? We can certainly stop if you wish. However, wasn't the goal to get it working at 1Gb? Isn't that what it shows now?

Comment: The speed is correct now. The only potential problem is whether the ethernet-connection between my laptop and my router will drop again if I disconnect the Cat 5E cable and connect it again. :-)

Comment: @HenrikR. lets try it and see!